# How to access other class method from an Android class?

Tags: android

My app contains three classes: main Activity, View_A, View_B.

View_B needs to access a non-static method of View_A. How to do that ?

Both View_A and View_B have been initialized in the main activity in the onCreate method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could store View_A as a public instance variable within your Main Activity. then pass the context of main activity to View_B. You can then access the instance of View_A via the context of main activity within View_B.

Here's basically what i mean

This is in your main Activity:

```
Context context;
public View_A viewA;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  context = this;

  viewA = new View_A();
  View_B viewB = new View_B(context);
}
```

it would probably be better using a getter method to get the viewA from context.

Here is View_B example class:

```
     class View_B {   
Context activityContext;

     // constructor   
     View_B (Context _c)
     {
         activityContext = _c;
         viewA = activityContext.viewA;   
      }    
    }
```

that is basically what i mean, but as i said in my comment, Teds solution seems more elegant.

I think he meant something more like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  context = this;

  View_A viewA = new View_A();
  View_B viewB = new View_B();
  // create a setter method in viewB class to set viewA instance into it after viewA & viewB are created. or i guess you could pass viewA to viewB in the constructor of viewB
  viewb.setViewA(viewA);
}
```

I hope something from that can help you out

Comment: see my updates. I have included sample of what i meant but like i said i think Teds solution is more elegant

Answer (score 1):

It is siple.You jst need to create the reference of need class in you current class and call the method with referenceedObject.methodName();

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a reference to View_A inside View_B. One way to do that is to define a View_A variable in View_B that is accessible to the activity class. In onCreate, just set the variable to the instance of View_A once both View_A and View_B have been created.

Comment: ahh this is a more efficient way than mine as it is not passing the context to View_B